# Can an embedded Flash object access the DOM of its parent document?

Tags: javascript, flash, dom

I'm just curious if it's possible that Flash objects can access the DOM of the document that has embedded it.

Answer (score 7):

Yes, through the ExternalInterface class.

You can make calls to Javascript from within the Flash movie and get back any public information about the page that your heart desires.

**Addendum**

Looking at this a year and a half later, i decided to add some examples:

Say you have a JS function on your client page like this:

```
function foo(bar,type) {
  // do something with bar and type
}
```

You call it from Flash (using AS3) like so:

```
ExternalInterface.call(foo, bar, type);
```

Note that the function name is the first object and the arguments are listed sequentially thereafter.

To expose a method of the Flash movie to outside Javascript, you would do this in your Flash or Flex (again, AS3):

```
application1_applicationCompleteHandler(event:Event) {
  // the app has finished loading, so do whatever we
  // have to do on load, plus add that callback
  ExternalInterface.addCallback(foo, bar);
}

public function bar(arg1, arg2) : void {
  // do something with arg1 and arg2
}
```

In the Javascript on the page you invoke it like this (where myMovie is the ID of the SWF):

```
myMovie.foo(anArg, anotherArg);
```

In the `addCallback` method, the first argument is the external name of the function, and the second argument is the closure that will get called.

Comment: how about getting attribute from a dom object? Example : `<div data-url="http://google.com"></div>`? How do i get the data attribute?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes**.

An example: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=ProgrammingHTMLAndJavaScript_07.html

Comment: As I understand it, that example is for AIR applications only and can't be used in regular web browsers. So the other answers, suggesting to use ExternalInterface, are probably a better fit, unless  devviedev is developing an AIR application.

Answer (score 3):

Not that I know of, but they can execute javascript in the containing document, which obviously can then access the DOM itself.

Comment: If I have some AJAX calls in the parent document, can I communicate with the Flash object somehow?