# How to get the HTML body text from an AS3 based webapp?

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3

I would like to get the HTML body text of a website through a Flash based webapp.
What is the best way to do this?

Comment: Take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2473053/can-an-embedded-flash-object-access-the-dom-of-its-parent-document

Answer (score -1):

Right click the scroll bar if there is one.